# $f^!=f^*[d]$ for quasismooth maps?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, six-operations

Given a smooth map of schemes $f:X\to Y$ of relative dimension $d$, then there is a natural isomorphism $f^!\simeq f^*[d](2d)$ (in any context where the six operations are defined; see Cesinski-Deglise).

If $f$ is a smooth map of *Artin stacks* I imagine the same is true (there is a notion of the six operations for Artin stacks: https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5948).

> **Question:** Let $f:X\to Y$ be a **quasismooth** map of Artin stacks (say also flat to rule out things like closed embeddings). Is it still true that $f^!\simeq f^*[d](2d)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I think this should fail for most non-smooth local complete intersections.
For a specific example, let $X = \mathbb V(xy) \subset \mathbb A^2$  and $Y = *$.  Then the stalk at the dualizing complex of $X$ at the origin is $\mathbb Q_l[1] \oplus \mathbb Q_l[2]^{\oplus 2}$, contradicting the local constancy of $f^! \mathbb Q_l = \omega_X$.

Comment: Thanks. Should that be $\mathbf{Q}_\ell\oplus\mathbf{Q}_\ell[1]$?

Comment: @Meow  I just did the calculation, and I think we were both wrong. It's $H_*(X,X-0) = \mathbb Q_l[1] \oplus \mathbb Q_l [2]^{\oplus 2}$.  Comes from $\mathbf D i^* \omega_X = i^! \mathbb Z_X.$  How are you getting your answer?

Comment: Sorry, that was a guess not a computation on my part. Thanks!